# How should last colum occupy remaining space in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I have my `jqgrid` with `shrinkToFit: false` and `autowidth: true`
what I want is the columns should take their respective width specified in the column model and it does. But when the column number is less and the width of grid is more, there is hell lot of space left behind after the last column.

I need the last column to resize to occupy the full available space.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have very special requirements. Resizing of the last column to the full available space is not standard feature of jqGrid so you can't use `autowidth: true` in the case.

What you can do is generating the `width` value of the last column of `colModel` and the value of `width` option of jqGrid **before** the grid will be created. It allows you to implement your custom requirements.